# Why does Fubini's Theorem fail?

Tags: measure-theory

The following version of Fubini's theorem is from Aliprantis and Border:

> Fubini's Theorem: Assume that $\mu: \mathcal{S}_{1} \rightarrow[0, \infty]$ and $v: \mathcal{S}_{2} \rightarrow[0, \infty]$
>   are measures on two semirings of subsets of the sets $X$ and $Y,$ and $Y,$ respectively. If
>   $f: X \times Y \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a $\mu \times v$ -integrable function, then both iterated integ rals $\iint f d v d \mu$
>   and $\iint f d \mu d v$ exist and
>   $$
> \int f d(\mu \times v)=\iint f d v d \mu=\iint f d \mu d v
> $$

A classical example that fails Fubini's theorem is the following from wikipedia:

> Suppose that X is the unit interval with the Lebesgue measurable sets and Lebesgue measure, and Y is the unit interval with all subsets measurable and the counting measure, so that Y is not σ-finite. If f is the characteristic function of the diagonal of X×Y, then integrating f along X gives the 0 function on Y, but integrating f along Y gives the function 1 on X. So the two iterated integrals are different.

I understand why the example fails Tonelli's version of the theorem because one measure is not $\sigma$-finite. However, why does it fail the cited theorem?

Comment: can you even define product measure without sigma finite?

Comment: I think $\sigma$-finiteness is needed for uniqueness, but not for existence.

Comment: You can still obtain a Fubini theorem for products of $s$-finite measures but like Martin said it's not uniquely determined by what it does on the measurable rectangles.